# I'm building a social media website and need terms and conditions template. What is the best way to get it?

Tags: social-media, terms-of-use

I was thinking of getting certain sections from different websites to use to build my terms and conditions or can I just use twitters terms and conditions ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to copy someone's terms and conditions, you should be sure they have not copyrighted those terms. Most companies pay lawyers to draw up their terms, so would not like to be paying for their competitors to be using those terms as well! However, try looking at terms for similar services that may be open source. Maybe someone in the Diaspora project has something that they make free for others to use. Or develop your own terms by studying the concepts applied in terms from several competitors so that they cannot come after you.

Ideally, you should have a lawyer draw up your terms, but this is beyond the budget of many developers in early stages.